# String.prototype.replace === String.replace

Tags: javascript

When I use `call()` or `apply()`, I got a problem.

```
console.log(String.prototype.replace === String.replace);//false
```

I think `String.replace` should be equal with `String.prototype.replace`, because they are the same Object.

However,they are different from each other.

What happens when I run the code below:

```
var s = "a b c";
String.replace.call(s,'a','A');//return "a"
```

Why  doesn't this code throw an error, but return a value?

Comment: there is obviously some enhancements in the prototype internals, just because it generally returns the same result...

Comment: `String.replace.call(s,'a','A');` throws an error because it's not a function. What happens if you execute `String.replace` without `()`? What code do you obtain?

Comment: @pimvdb i run these code in firefox,String.replace returns function replace() { [native code]} .besides, it dont throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a lot of mixed information here. First of all we have to clarify that the `String` constructor function [does not have a `replace` method](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.5.3).

So, whatever `String.replace` is in Firefox, it is non-standard and therefore you should stay away from it. [A quick test in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/GmFmR/1/) shows that `String.replace` indeed does not exist there.

Unfortunately I cannot tell you where `String.replace` comes from in Firefox. [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) does not mention it. But it seems that it is not an inherited property, as `String.hasOwnProperty('replace')` returns `true`.

---

Now to some points in your question:

> I think `String.replace` should be equal with `String.prototype.replace`, because they are the same Object.

Obviously they are not. If they were, it would return `true`. Also: `String !== String.prototype`.

The `replace` method which is used by the string instances is `String.prototype.replace`. So if you want to use `call` or `apply`, you them on this method.

> Why doesn't this code throw an error, but return a value?

In order to answer that, we would have to know what that method is doing. Maybe a look at the Firefox or Spidermonkey source provides some information.

If you are confused about how prototype inheritance works, have a look at the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) - [Details of the object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) and [Inheritance revisited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited).

Answer (score 0):

This will be true:

```
(new String()).replace === String.prototype.replace
```

And this will not:

```
String.prototype.replace === String.replace
```

`String` is a constructor, this is just a function.

`String.prototype` is an object where other objects created with `new String()` will search for properties if they will not have some.

`new String()` creates a new object. Consider this:

```
var s = new String();
s.replace(...);
```

Actually `s` has no replace method. By prototype of its constructor has, thats why call for this method will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `replace()` method is `string.replace()`, where `string` has to be a string, **not** the String object.

Comment: The String object is valid, but `String.replace` doesn't exist. So `String.replace == undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GmFmR/. In chrome at least these are not the same.

String.replace() takes the first argument as the string it will search to replace and then uses the rest of the arguments and pumps them into String.prototype.replace() using method.apply

**Edit:**

Per your comment for more detail

String.replace()

```
function (item){
    return method.apply(item, slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

String.prototype.replace()

```
function replace() { [native code] }
```

This is what the jsfiddle I have above renders in the Chrome console.

Comment: You are wrong. In your fiddle, `String.replace` is a method added by Mootools. Have a look at this fiddle which does not include any libraries: http://jsfiddle.net/GmFmR/1/

Comment: My mistake, I knew it wasn't part of the core framework so I assumed it was something Chrome added since that was the browser I was using